# Does `perf trace -p <PID>` trace all threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, perf

`strace -f -p <PID>` traces system calls in all threads of a multi-threaded process.  (This also follows forks, there is an option `-b execve` that tries to address that).

Does `perf trace -p <PID>` trace all threads of the process?  It *looks* like it should do, because it also has a `--tid` option.

I think I traced all the `gnome-shell` PIDs on my system.  But, at the same time I ran `perf trace -a`.  I filtered both traces using `-e fsync`.  The global trace showed `gnome-shell` tasks calling fsync.  But the PID-specific trace did not.

In the global trace, the task was identified as either `gnome-shell/9822` or `pool/9822`.  The call stack for the `fsync` call (I used `--call-graph=dwarf`) looks very thready: the bottom two entries were `__GI___clone` and `start_thread (/usr/lib64/libpthread-2.27.so)`.  I can't find this thread in the current output of `ps -eLF`.  Based on this and the name `pool`, I suspect it was a temporary worker thread.  Does `perf trace -p <PID>` perhaps not follow newly created threads?

Version: perf-4.19.3-200.fc28.x86_64

Comment: No, perf trace -p doesn't follow newly created threads, even 4 years later.